# Deleting files from "My Files" folder

Tags: samsung

If I delete files from the "My Files" folder on a Samsung Galaxy S8, are the files permanently deleted?? My phone's internal memory says it is low and that I need to delete files from my files folder.

Answer (score 1):

"My files" is a built-in file manager and explorer. Any files deleted using that are permanently deleted

As pointed out in [comments by Arctiic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221642/deleting-files-from-my-files-folder/221643?noredirect=1#comment286990_221643), it appears some files get restored even after deletion. I wasn't aware of this

Comment: Thank you beeshyams.

Comment: You are welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Since you are new and don't yet have the reputation to up vote, you can tick the green arrow next to the answer to indicate that you have "accepted" it. There is absolutely no compulsion to accept my answer.

Comment: See this to  better understand [what it means to accept an answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: That's not necessarily true though, some files in secured directories will get restored on reboot even if deleted, and can't be easily removed persistently without root.

Comment: @Arctiic Restore is user triggered isn't it? It is not automatic. That's what I recollect. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @beeshyams Apologies for the confusion, I wasn't referring to the `restore` function (ADB or settings toggle), but rather just the more ubiquitous usage of the term.  I don't actually know how the restoration is actioned, only that certain files, e.g. for my Samsung Note 8, `/SD Card/Samsung/Music/Over_the_Horizon.mp3` will appear again on it's own after deleting it.  My guess is it's a symlink of some sort or the file is on some sort of system whitelist somewheie, thus it reappears regardless of user interventions.

Comment: @Arctiic Thanks. Included in solution. Feel free to improve. Thanks

Comment: @Arctiic the mentioned `.mp3` file is Samsung's ringtone. It must be in `/system/media` or some other read-only filesystem, simply copied to external storage on reboot. Deleted files are never restored this way.